# Python convert integer to 16-byte bytes

Tags: python, cryptography, type-conversion, data-conversion

I'm trying to use AES-CTR-128 in my code. I use Python 2.7 and utilize the `cryptography` module to do the encryption.

I need to set specific Counter value, for example counter_iv = 112. When I tried

```
import os
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
backend = default_backend()
key = os.urandom(32)
counter_iv = 112
cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CTR(counter_iv), backend=backend)
encryptor = cipher.encryptor()
ciphertext = encryptor.update(b"a secret message") + encryptor.finalize()
```

This gave me an error message:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "aestest.py", line 14, in <module>
>   cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CTR(counter_iv), backend=backend)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/modes.py", line 139, in __init__
>   raise TypeError("nonce must be bytes")
> TypeError: nonce must be bytes
> ```

I think it tells me that counter_iv should be a 16-byte string.

My question is how to convert a integer, or maybe a long integer into a 16-byte string?

Moreover, is there any way to convert an integer to any length string? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is `encryptor`?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham Forgot to add it. Now it's there.

Comment: **Warning**: Your counter should not be static, certainly not for CTR mode. Please understand the differences between a nonce and the counter value, or your scheme may be **very** insecure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 2, you can convert an integer to a byte string in little endian like this:

```
counter_iv = 112  # This can be a pretty big number
iv_bytes = "".join(chr((counter_iv >> (i * 8)) & 0xFF) for i in range(16))
```

---

Expanding the code to explain:

```
counter_iv = 112  # Can be from 0 to 3.40e38
temp = []  # Will be an array of bytes
for i in range(16):
    # Get the i'th byte counting from the least significant end
    b = (counter_iv >> (i * 8)) & 0xFF
    temp.append(b)
# For example, temp == [0x70, 0x00, ... 0x00]

# Will be an array of 1-character strings
temp2 = [chr(b) for b in temp]
# For example, temp2 == ['\x70', '\x00', ..., '\x00']

# Concatenate all the above together
iv_bytes = "".join(temp2)
# For example, iv_bytes == '\0x70\0x00...\0x00'
```

Comment: Great it works. Could you give me a brief explain of this? Thanks.

Comment: In python3, you can simply `counter_iv.to_bytes(16,"little")`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham That is awesome! Learned something new today

Answer (score 5):

First do you have a good reason to use the low level *hazardous material* instead of the higher level API? This level is intended to be used only through the high level API of for special purposes.

Next, you are misleading any further reader by writing `modes.CTR(counter_iv)`, because the *counter* mode does not use an initialization vector but a *nonce* according to its [documentation](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/symmetric-encryption/#symmetric-encryption-modes). And the error you get is normal, since the doc states the nonce shall be a byte string *of same size of the cipher block* so for AES it must be 128 bits or 16 bytes.

BTW the doc also states that a nonce should never be reused

> ... It is critical to never reuse a nonce with a given key. Any reuse of a nonce with the same key compromises the security of every message encrypted with that key.

Nayuki's answer explain how to build a 16 bytes string from your int, but be sure to correctly use cryptography if you use the low level *hazardous material*

Comment: Your answer gives a lot of insight into how the library should be used correctly. Thank you :)